# How to check if Chromecast is playing media or paused in Swift iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, chromecast

I need to determine if the Chromecast remote media client is currently playing media or if it's paused in Swift. Chromecast provides the two following methods:

```
GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.play()
GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.pause()
```

But I can't seem to find any property to determine if it's currently playing or paused.

The equailvant property for what I'm looking for in AVPlayer is:

```
avPlayer.timeControlStatus == .playing
```

What is the equivalent way to do this (check if media is playing or paused) in Chromecast?

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as:
`GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient?.mediaStatus?.playerState`

This is an enum with all the cases you're looking for (see: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/g_c_k_media_status_8h))